# error: accessing members of protocol type value 'String' is unimplemented

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to put 3 values in an array in Swift programming language and I'm getting an error.

Here is the code:

```
var a = txtSchool.text
var b = txtDegree.text
var c = txtYear.text.toInt()        
eduData.append(a, b, c!)
```

The array in another file is:

```
var eduData = [String , String , Int]()
```

Xcode gives me an error:

```
accessing members of protocol type value 'String' is unimplemented
```

I want to store three textfields in an array and then I want to show it in a table view.  When I get all values in variables, and try to store them in an array.

What does the error mean and what am I doing to cause it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're giving the array multiple types to hold, Swift infers that you want an array of tuples:

```
var eduData = [String, String, Int]()
let object1 = ("a", "b", 42)
let object2 = ("c", "d", 33)
eduData.append(object1)
eduData.append(object2)
print(eduData)           // prints [(a, b, 42), (c, d, 33)]
```

Each object in the array is a tuple:

```
print(eduData[0].0)     // prints "a"
print(eduData[0].1)     // prints "b"
print(eduData[0].2)     // prints 42
```

Comment: sir,  my array is in another file

Comment: sir i was just tried your way, but now it give me error : missing argument for parameter #2 in call

Comment: It is not "my way", it is an explanation of why your code example gives you the error you get, plus an example of how to use your array of tuples. :)  *But* if you still have errors, it means maybe you don't actually need your array of tuples? In this case, you can either edit your question and add details, context and more of your code; or create a new question with your new code and the new error.

Comment: yes, still i have that problem. no one tell me how to use an array that is declared in another file.